# Converting Ruby objects to Javascript objects for interpolation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, json

What is a good way to convert some common Ruby objects (like strings, hashes, arrays) into corresponding Javascript objects? For example, jQuery `css()` accepts a hash as an argument. Suppose I have a Ruby hash like this:

```
h = {"background-color" => "yellow", "color" => "green"}
```

I want to embed this ruby object into a string so that it becomes a valid javascript (jQuery) command. My best attempt now is to convert it via json like this:

```
"$('#foo').css(JSON.parse('#{h.to_json}'));"
```

but it is not working well. I want a more direct and working way to do it. Is there a good way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to convert to a string and then JSON.parse:

```
"$('#foo').css(#{h.to_json});"
```

Or if you break it out...

```
var h = #{h.to_json};
"$('#foo').css(h);"
```

Which is rendered to the client as:

```
var h = {"background-color":"yellow","color":"green"};
$('#foo').css(h);
```

Comment: So a json string is automatically parsed as json within javascript?

Comment: @sawa Well, basically.  It's parsed as JavaScript, and short of a corner case or two, JSON is a subset of JavaScript.